# Fileupload control enter button is not working

Tags: asp.net

I am having a file upload control in my page and when i run the application and try to navigate to the file upload control by pressing the tab key. When the focus is on the Browse button and if i hit the enter button the file browse window is not opening.It just moves the focus to the next control.Please help.

Replication steps:
1) Add a file upload contol in a web page
2) add a button in the same page
3) run the application and try to use tab key to navigate to the browse button in the file upload button control
4) press the enter button
5) the control will move to the next button.

Regards,
Jebli.

Comment: Does the button work if you click on it?

Comment: Yes .It works when i use the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that your browser interprets the ENTER keypress as a request to submit the form.  You need to intercept and override this in javascript.  See:

http://bytes.com/groups/javascript/644728-file-upload-change-key-code-enter-key-browse-button

Comment: Stop helping all the people I go to help 5 minutes too late. This is becoming a nuisance.

Comment: I know what you mean.  I feel the same way about Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the default browser behavior is that enter executes a submit.  Space bar should open the browser window when your button has focus.  You would need to change this behavior with JavaScript if it is that important to you.

Comment: Yes space bar is opening the file browse dialoge box.But is there any idea on how to do this using javascript ?